# TomTom traffic api integration in ESRI js api

Tags: javascript, maps, esri, traffic, tomtom

I'm facing issues displaying results from the TomTom API in my ArcGIS JavaScript application. Despite configuring a Vector Tile Layer with TomTom traffic data, the results are not showing up on the map. I'm seeking assistance in identifying and resolving the problem.

Code Snippet:

javascript
this does not show anything on the map but it makes requests for the traffic data and returns the data as .pbf file

```
 let vectorTileLayer = new VectorTileLayer({
    title: 'TomTom Traffic',
    style: {
      version: 8,
      sources: {
        tomtom: {
          type: 'vector',
          tileCompression: "gzip",
          tiles: ["https://c.api.tomtom.com/traffic/map/4/tile/flow/absolute/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf?key={api-key}"],
          minzoom: 0,
          maxzoom: 22,
        },
      },
      layers: [
        {
          id: 'Traffic flow',
          type: 'fill',
          source: 'tomtom',
          'source-layer': 'public',
          paint: {
            'fill-color': 'red',
            'fill-opacity': 0.2,
            'fill-outline-color': 'blue',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  });
```

this works but it is an image tiles

```
 let tileLayer = new WebTileLayer({
    title: 'TomTom Traffic',
    urlTemplate: "https://c.api.tomtom.com/traffic/map/4/tile/flow/relative/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key={api-key}&thickness=8&tileSize=512",
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 22,
  });
```

Issue Details:

I have set up a Vector Tile Layer with TomTom traffic data using the ArcGIS API for JavaScript.
The TomTom API URL and parameters have been configured correctly.
There are no console errors or warnings, but the results are not visible on the map.
Additional Information:

What steps should I take to troubleshoot and identify the reason why results from the TomTom API are not displaying?
Are there common challenges or considerations when integrating TomTom API results with the ArcGIS JavaScript API?
Are there specific debugging techniques or tools I can use to inspect the TomTom API response and understand why it's not rendering on the map?

I have verified the TomTom API key and ensured that it is valid.
Other layers, such as WebTileLayer, are displaying correctly.
I'm using version 4.21 of the ArcGIS API for JavaScript.

Comment: You are trying to view 'public' layer from this TomTom source. But it actually contains multiple layers. You need to use style provided by TomTom (for example: https://api.tomtom.com/traffic/map/4/style/20.2.4-0/flow_absolute.json?key={Your_API_Key}) or create one using Map Maker.
You can check docs here: https://developer.tomtom.com/traffic-api/documentation/map-styles/map-styles
and please, remove API keys from your question

Comment: thank you very much for responding the proplem was indeed in the source layer once i provided the source layer the code worked .  about the api key its a trail api and i provided it in case some one helping need to try the code still i removed it though